# Updation bug in php file when data updated via android app

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am making Android app in this app on registration activity I have 5 fields.

[image]

When I try to update any field then that field updated successfully but next field automatically blank.

Following is my update query:

```
 $string_query = "UPDATE TABLE 'tbl_kunal' WHERE `user_name`='$user_name',
 `user_email`='$user_email',

 `user_password`='$user_password',`user_mobile` ='$user_mobile' 
 WHERE `user_id`='$user_id' ;"
```

[image: update.php]

**update code in android**

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Up_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("mytag", "" + response);
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(KEY_ID, editText_id.getText().toString());
                params.put(KEY_NAME, editText_name.getText().toString());
                params.put(KEY_EMAIL, editText_email.getText().toString());
                params.put(KEY_PASSWORD, editText_pass.getText().toString());
                params.put(KEY_MOBILE, editText_mob.getText().toString());

                Log.d("mytag", "parms : :" + params);
                return params;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how remove this error? 
All suggestions are welcome.

**Note: I am not able to format my php file so that's why I am adding image of php file**

Comment: Is the data in your database actually updated? Your query is missing the "SET column=value" part. The full query should be: 

"UPDATE TABLE 'tbl_kunal' SET `user_name`='$user_name',
user_email='$user_email', user_password='$user_password', user_mobile ='$user_mobile' WHERE user_id='$user_id' ;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is malformed. You have two WHERE clauses instead of SET clause:

```
$string_query = "UPDATE TABLE 'tbl_kunal' 
SET `user_name`='$user_name',  `user_email`='$user_email', `user_password`='$user_password',`user_mobile` ='$user_mobile' 
WHERE `user_id`='$user_id' ;
```

Edit: You are storing the password in plaintext. Anyone who makes a select into user's table could get the user and password. I recommend you to encode passwords with HASH function.

Comment: MD5 is not cryptographically strong and should NOT be used to hash passwords. I'd recommend using SHA-2 instead.